# Does the 2018 MacBook Air come with a NVMe SSD?

Tags: macbook-pro

Does the 2018 MacBook Air come with a NVMe SSD?

I believe the MacBook Pro does, since 2017, however I'm finding no information one way or another for MBA 2018.

Comment: Do you *actually* need to know whether it's NVMe, or are you simply looking for replacement aftermarket storage? The 2018 MacBook Air has no replaceable storage; it's soldered & can't be changed once shipped. https://everymac.com/systems/apple/macbook-air/specs/macbook-air-core-i5-1.6-13-retina-display-late-2018-specs.html

Comment: NVMe is new to me, it seems like a benefit to have, and I had seen no explicit statement on it for the MBA. Look at any given spec list and they'll say "SSD" but as we all know not every SSD is the same, and compared to SSD's from 8 years ago, surely there's improvements? Just trying to make informed purchases.

Comment: @marsandback Yes, SSDs comes in many different speeds and qualities. Apple’s SSDs in the MBP are these days some of the very best, if no the best, consumer grade SSDs. The MBA does not have the same SSDs, but they’re still very fast. Expect approx 2 GB/s sustained read and 1 GB/s sustained write here. Many laptops in this category have disks with less than half of that speed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the SSD is NVMe.

However note that this does not mean that it can be replaced with any NVMe. The MBA Retina does not have a user-replaceable SSD.

Also note that you cannot directly compare two NVMe SSDs. Their performance and price points may vary wildly.